# mmaping huge file and then restricting the memory with cgroups

Tags: c, linux, mmap, cgroups

I'm trying to test some things with mmap as part of a larger experiment. I'm trying to mmap a large file (say 20GB), and then do some writes to the entire mmaped array. As I understand it now, kernel will try to allocate 20GB of RAM for my program if my program tries to write data to all blocks of the 20GB file. This runs fine, since my machine has well over 32GB of RAM and most of it is not in use.

However, I'm also trying to restrict the memory of the programs **while it's running** using linux cgroups.

Initially, I run the program that creates the mmap without any memory restrictions. The 20GB of RAM is claimed as expected. But then while the program is running, I want to write my own memory limit (say 1GB) to the cgroup in which my program is running as follows:`echo 1000000000 > /var/cgroups/mycgroup/memory.limit_in_bytes`.

By doing this, what happens to the remaining 19GB that was reserved for the mmap by the process? Does it just get immediately reclaimed by the kernel? If so, what happens to my still-running program, which would like to be able to keep reading and writing from the mmaped array? Is there a way to make it so that the running program will read/write to the disk if the memory given to it was snatched by the kernel?

Comment: A quick glance at the source suggests that an attempt to reduce the limit below current usage will fail, with EBUSY.  Have you tested it?

Comment: This is indeed what I observed, however for me it would sometimes work and sometimes fail. I am not sure why it would sometimes enable me to lower memory limit to below the usage. Is there any other feasible way to reduce memory consumption at runtime that you might know of?

Comment: I think it depends what you mean by "consumption".  For instance, if another process needs a lot of memory, AFAIK the kernel can simply write back some of the dirty pages of your mapping to the underlying file, and give those pages to the other process.  So in that sense, the memory used for your mapping is not really "consumed" in the first place.

Comment: If you want to encourage the kernel to flush pages sooner, there is `madvise()`.

Comment: Here's really what I'm trying to do. Let's say I start a program with 20GB of file-backed mmap memory and no memory restrictions. The kernel will allocate 20GB of RAM so periodically flush this RAM to disk. What I want is to be able to reduce this memory to, let's say 5GB, so that the remaining 15GB gets reclaimed by the kernel. The dirty pages in the 15GB should be immediately flush to disk. If my program wants to then use the 15GB of memory which was just reclaimed by the kernel, it have to evict other parts of the 5GB it is given to make room for it.

Comment: Cgroups is broken in terms of memory accounting. Processes with limitations have weird behaviors in terms of IO. 

The block cache counts toward memory, but if you run out, but the machine hasn't, IO operations don't block, but fail with ENOMEM, but if you're out of the container (or the system runs out) IO ops block. It's all very inconsistent and hard to debug. I'm not sure how it will interact with the memory manager.